# rerender a page with the correct route in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

learing to work with zend framework, I am facing some minor problem.
I create a login form with Zend_Form, and then in my Controller I call my form in my controller

Here is the layout of my module

*Module:        compte

controller: compteController

Action:     loginAction*

In my application.ini I create a resource for my login route like this:

*resources.router.routes.login.route = /compte/login

resources.router.routes.login.defaults.module = compte 

resources.router.routes.login.defaults.controller = compte 

resources.router.routes.login.defaults.action = login*

I then call the login page like this exemple.com/compte/login **the problem is that when validating the form, if the is an error the login page display again which is correct but with the total route exemple.com/compte/compte/login**.

My question is that how can I correct this problem so that when the form is not valid the form re-display with correct address in the explorer.

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the form's action set to?

Maybe you need to do `$form->setAction('/compte/login');` in the view or controller.

Answer (score 0):

you could do somthing like:

```
if ($form->isValid($_POST) {//This is not real code just for example.

//do some stuff

} else {
    $this->view->errors = $form->getErrors();
    //should go back exactly where you came from
    $this->_redirect($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
}
```